# How to access a method in one inherited tkinter class from another inherited tkinter class

Tags: python, user-interface, inheritance, tkinter

I've programmed using tkinter before, but usually did a long procedural GUI class that implemented other non GUI classes I've created. This time I wanted to do it using more OOP making it more modular.

I ran into a problem, I've searched for answers and haven't found any, which usually means it's either really easy or I'm really wrong. I created an inherited classes from tk.LabelFrame and created GUI widgets in them. I also have methods to manipulate the widgets in the classes but I can't figure out how to execute a function in another inherited class, partly because I can't figure out how to correctly instantiate an object from the other class (which have tkinter ('parent') objects as parameters).

Would I do this by overloading constructors? I've seen something about @classmethods and *args, **kwargs but haven't acted on them as I'm not sure if that's the right route either. There's some debate about the best/correct way to implement an overloaded constructor in python. I'm stumped as to what is the most apropos for what I'm trying to accomplish...

Thanks

```
#python 2.7 on win7
import Tkinter as tk

class Testing(tk.LabelFrame):
    buttonwidth = 10

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.parent=parent
        #results = Results(???) #<-- Don't know how to instantiate Results object

        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, self.parent, 
            text="Test Operations",
            padx=10,
            pady=10,
        )

        self.taskButton = tk.Button(
            self, 
            text="Do A Task", 
            width=self.buttonWidth,
            command=self.doATask,
        )

        self.taskButton.pack()

    def doATask(self):
        #want to execute function in Results.getResult() but don't know how
        #results.getResults()  #<--what I want to do
        print("place holder")

class Results(tk.LabelFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, self.parent, text="Visual Results")

        self.resultLbl = tk.Label(self, text="Result")

        self.resultLbl.pack()

    def getResult(self):
        self.resultLbl.configure(bg='yellow')



class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.parent)

        self.Testing = Testing(self.parent)
        self.Results = Results(self.parent)

        self.Testing.pack(fill=tk.X)
        self.Results.pack(fill=tk.X)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Modular GUI App")

    Application(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend sticking to instance variables, which are created for each individual object, unlike class variables which are shared among all of a class's instantiations - just prepend those variable names with `self.` (e.g. `self.results`). Also, stick to naming conventions so you don't have a `Testing` class and a `Testing` object of that class.

You instantiate objects according to their `__init__`. The `Results` class has an `__init__` defined as `def __init__(self, parent):`, so it needs a parent. If you want it to have the same parent as the `Testing` object that created it, simply do `results = Results(parent)`. However, you don't want to do this (see below).

A problem that I encountered after making the above change was that the `Application` class instantiated its own `Results` object, and that was what was actually being displayed, not the one created by the `Testing` object. Refer back to that object instead of creating a new one. Pass the `Application` object to each of these classes so they can refer to each other. Now, having said that, it's generally better to have each class know as little about other classes as possible, so that making a change in one class doesn't require any changes in other classes.

The following code will make the label yellow when you click the button.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Testing(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, main):

        self.buttonWidth = 10

        self.parent=parent
        self.main = main # save the instantiating class

        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, self.parent, 
            text="Test Operations",
            padx=10,
            pady=10
        )

        self.taskButton = tk.Button(
            self, 
            text="Do A Task", 
            width=self.buttonWidth,
            command=self.doATask,
        )

        self.taskButton.pack()

    def doATask(self):
        #want to execute function in Results.getResult() but don't know how
        self.main.results.getResult()  #<--what you can do

class Results(tk.LabelFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent, main):
        self.parent = parent
        self.main = main # save the instantiating class
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, self.parent, text="Visual Results")

        self.resultLbl = tk.Label(self, text="Result")

        self.resultLbl.pack()

    def getResult(self):
        self.resultLbl.config(bg='yellow')

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.parent)

        self.testing = Testing(self.parent, self)
        self.results = Results(self.parent, self)

        self.testing.pack(fill=tk.X)
        self.results.pack(fill=tk.X)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Modular GUI App")

    Application(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Excellent... I kept thinking I needed to find a way to overload a constructor but didn't seem quite right to me. This is what I needed. I'll keep in mind what you said about keeping classes oblivious of one another.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
Results(None,None).getResult()
```

goodluck!